# How do you set up a chart.js scatter line chart through angular-chart.js?

Tags: angularjs, chart.js, scatter-plot, angular-chart

Angular-chart.js is a wrapper around chart.js. I want to create a scatter line chart as described [here.](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#line-chart-scatter-line-charts)
The angular-chart.js documentation has [a clear example of how to set up a line chart](http://jtblin.github.io/angular-chart.js/#line-chart), and I have that working. I haven't been able to figure out how to pass the angular directive the correct data for a scatter line graph.

To clarify, [chart.js takes two data formats](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#line-chart-data-points). I have the first format working in both chart.js and angular-chart.js. I have the second format working through chart.js but not through angular-chart.js. Could you provide a hello world example of a scatter plot through angular-chart.js?

I assumed that something like this would have worked based on the documentation from the two projects:

```
$scope.data = {
            datasets: [{
                label: 'Scatter Dataset',
                data: [{
                    x: -10,
                    y: 0
                }, {
                    x: 0,
                    y: 10
                }, {
                    x: 10,
                    y: 5
                }]
            }]
        };
```

That $scope.data would go in the controller [as found on the angular-chart.js documentation](http://jtblin.github.io/angular-chart.js/#line-chart)

Comment: http://stackblitz.com/edit/dynamic-data-chart-g4kjvz?file=src/app/app.component.html Please find the solution in the above link. Please import file in your respective module as done here and please install respective version as you can see in package.json

Answer (score 0):

I think you're close. I think the only thing you need to do is to change your options and make a few minor modifications (it took a while for me to get it to work; originally, I tried what you had posted):

In your .js file:

```
$scope.data = [{
    x: -10,
    y: 0
}, {
    x: 0,
    y: 10
}, {
    x: 10,
    y: 5
}];

// The angular-chart directive will use this as the label
$scope.series = ['Scatter Dataset'];

$scope.options = {
    scales: {
        xAxes: [{
            type: 'linear',
            position: 'bottom'
        }]
    }
};
```

And then, in your html file:

```
<canvas class="chart chart-line"
        chart-data="data"
        chart-series="series"
        chart-options="options">
</canvas>
```